# SessionStateProxy Variable with Runspace Pools

Tags: powershell, runspace

I wanted to use a Runspace Pool in PowerShell to perform Background actions. But I need to access the WPF Window Variable from the Main Thread.

Normal Runspaces have the option:

```
$runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable('xamGUI',$xamGUI)
```

But how do I do the same with a RunspacePool?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a little more involved to add a variable to a runspacepool, but still definitely doable. You will need to create an InitialSessionState object and then create a SessionStateVariableEntry object that contains the variable that you want to add to the runspacepool.

```
[int]$Test = 123498765
#Create the sessionstate variable entry
$Variable = New-object System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.SessionStateVariableEntry -ArgumentList 'Test',$Test,$Null
$InitialSessionState = [System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.InitialSessionState]::CreateDefault()

#Add the variable to the sessionstate
$InitialSessionState.Variables.Add($Variable)

#Create the runspacepool using the defined sessionstate variable
$RunspacePool = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1,$Throttle,$InitialSessionState,$Host)
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed, how on earth did you figure this out?