# How to suspend or buffering Write-Host in parallele runspace

Tags: powershell, command-line-interface

I use several 'Runspace' in parallel, they displays in the same console (in color) but all appears mixed and illegible.

is there a way to suspend or buffering "write-host" and release them by block ?

Comment: Create a `ConcurrentQueue`, set it as [a `SessionStateProxy` variable entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38102068/sessionstateproxy-variable-with-runspace-pools), then have the runspaces write their log messages (and coloring info) to that, and then dequeue the messages from that in the default runspace and call `Write-Host`

Comment: [Write-Host Considered Harmful](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/).